# Kotlin: Expression can't be invoked because function invoke() is not found

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to build an app where I implement Google maps. for some reason I get the error that the expression can't be invoked because the function invoke() is not found. I don't know how to fix this maybe one of you guys can help?

```
    package com.example.maxs.kotlinnearbyv2

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.maxs.kotlinnearbyv2.Common.Common
import com.example.maxs.kotlinnearbyv2.Model.MyPlaces
import com.example.maxs.kotlinnearbyv2.Remote.IGoogleAPIService
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_maps.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

private var latitude:Double=0.toDouble()
private var longitude:Double=0.toDouble()

lateinit var mService:IGoogleAPIService

internal var currentPlace: MyPlaces?=null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    //Init Service
    mService = Common.googleApiService

    bottom_navigation_view.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {item ->
        when(item.itemId)
        {
            R.id.action_hospital -> nearByPlace("hospital")
            R.id.action_restaurant -> nearByPlace("restaurant")
            R.id.action_market -> nearByPlace("market")
            R.id.action_school -> nearByPlace("school")
        }
    }
}

private fun nearByPlace(typePlace: String) {

    //Clear all marker on Map
    mMap.clear()
    //build URL request base on location
    val url = getUrl(latitude,longitude, typePlace)

    mService.getNearByPlaces(url)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<MyPlaces>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyPlaces>, response: Response<MyPlaces>) {

                currentPlace = response.body()

                if(response!!.isSuccessful)
                {
                    for(i in 0 until response!!.body()!!.results!!.size)
                    {
                        val markerOptions=MarkerOptions()
                        val googlePlace = response.body().results!!(i)
                        val lat = googlePlace.geometry!!.location!!.lat
                        val lng = googlePlace.geometry!!.location!!.lng
                        val placeName = googlePlace.name
                        val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)

                        markerOptions.position(latLng)
                        markerOptions.title(placeName)
                        if (typePlace.equals("hospital"))
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_local_hospital_black_24dp))
                        else if (typePlace.equals("market"))
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp))
                        else if (typePlace.equals("restaurant"))
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_black_24dp))
                        else if (typePlace.equals("school"))
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_school_black_24dp))
                        else
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))

                        markerOptions.snippet(i.toString())

                        //add marker to map
                        mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)


                    }
                    //move camera
                    mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(latitude, longitude)))
                    mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f))
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyPlaces>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, ""+t!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
}

private fun getUrl(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, typePlace: String): String {

    val googlePlaceUrl = StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("?location=$latitude,$longitude")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius=10000") //10 km
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&type=$typePlace")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&key=")

    Log.d("URL_DEBUG", googlePlaceUrl.toString())
    return googlePlaceUrl.toString()
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val barbier = LatLng(52.391274, 6.449712)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(barbier).title("Marker in Barbier"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(barbier))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(barbier, 15.0f))
}
}
```

I can't seem to find any solution and i'm probably think way to difficult…
the error is giving at the response.body()!!.results!!(i)

```
val googlePlace = response.body().results!!(i)
```

it sure is driving me crazy right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access an element in an array or list, use square brackets, e.g.:

```
array[i]
list[i] // or list.get(i)
results!![i]
```

Regarding the error message: Kotlin was assuming an [invoke operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke), which you didn't supply. You may want to read what an invoke-operator is good for. Sometimes it comes in very handy. But for your problem the square brackets should suffice.

As a (further) side-note: don't write your code with tons of `!!`, rather try to identify what can be `null` in the first place and omit the rest if it doesn't suit your needs, e.g.:

```
response?.also {
  if (it.isSuccessful) {
    it.body()?.results?.forEach {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Just a start... you may then want to simplify things even more... Just omit `!!` whenever possible... You may also want to read about [null safety in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) and maybe also about the [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Your `typePlace.equals(...`-conditions can also perfectly be replaced with [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), e.g.:

```
when(typePlace) {
  "hospital" -> ...
  "market" -> ...
```

That combined with either `let` or `also` may even further reduce your code, but that will probably be another story, better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As Roland mentioned, `()` is the invoke operator, and `[]` is the index operator. `()` is used for, among others, functions:

```
fun demo(func: (i: Int) -> Unit){
    // These are identical
    func(1)
    func.invoke(1)
}
```

`[]` is the [index operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed), which is what you want to apply here.

It can be used for any class that has an `operator fun get(args)`

```
class Demo {
    // These don't actually need a return type either. Or any arguments at all. 
    // If this was an int-containing class (i.e. a List), this would be the conventional declaration
    operator fun get(index: Int) : Int {
        return 0 // Obviously with an actual return value. 
    }

    // But they don't have to. They can have multiple, or no arguments. 
    operator fun get(index: Int, fallback: Int) : Int{
        return fallback
    }
}

fun test(){
    val demo = Demo()
    //Depending on arguments, the use is different. Single-arg is basic, and traditional:
    val value = demo[12];
    // But the multi-arg one can be useful depending on the class.
    val value2 = demo[12, 3];
}
```

I'm aware you didn't ask about declaring these, but the code is a part of my point:

- The index operator is applied to any class with an `operator fun get`, with any number of input args
- Lists, maps, and arrays have this method.

So you want to use `[index]`, not `(index)`. Alternatively, you could use the method, and use `.get(index)` directly. If you want to use null-safe calls (`?.`), you have to use `.get(index)`.

Also, you should generally prefer null-safe calls, optionally combined with `?.let{ }`, `?.forEach { }`, or similar, over using null assertion. First of all, it kinda defeats one of the core parts of Kotlin: Null safety. Secondly, if it ever is null, the app will crash instead of gracefully telling the user "Something went wrong". I am not familiar with the library you're using, so I'm honestly not sure what's null when, and if it can be null even if it is successful.

As for `let` and `forEach`, they're easier to use when you have nullability. Consider this:

```
someNullableIterable?.forEach {
    // Only invoked if the iterable isn't null
}
```

Compared to:

```
if(someNullableIterable!= null){
    for(item in someNullableIterable!!) { // Needs !! if the variable is global, and it's a var and not a val. 
        // Foo bar
    }
}
```

There's a bunch of similar functions too, and if you need to use indices as well, there's `forEachIndexed`. But just using `forEach` (alternatively `forEachIndexed`) will shorten some of your code, and better allow you to deal with nullability.